# Linux distro with PREEMPT_RT patch

Tags: kernel, distributions, real-time

I want to know if there is any Linux distribution with [PREEMPT_RT](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) kernel patch?

If not, is there any good tutorial on how to patch and compile a kernel with RT patch and how can I create kind of a dual boot of default Arch Linux kernel and my own kernel to boot into the same Linux instalation?

By the way, checking on my Android phone, I noticed that my Linux is `Linux localhost 2.6.32.9-FXP #1 PREEMPT Sat Apr 6 01:32:41 EEST 2013 armv7l GNU/Linux`, but I have a custom ROM installed on my phone, but I was wondering, are all Android phones patched with Linux PREEMPT kernel installed?

Edit: so, I have found a distribution with real time kernel called [AP-Linux](http://www.ap-linux.com/). Haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 3):

Debian provides the Linux kernel with an applied PREEMPT_RT patch. For example, to install the [amd64 version](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/linux-image-rt-amd64):

```
# aptitude install linux-image-rt-amd64
```

Similarly, Ubuntu also provides a [respective package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/amd64/linux-image-rt) in its Ubuntu Lucid repository:

```
# apt-get install linux-image-rt
```

**Update:** It looks like Ubuntu is [no longer developing](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RealTime) `linux-image-rt` packages.

> The -preempt and -rt kernels are no longer being developed due to lack of support. Focus has instead turned to the -lowlatency and -realtime kernels, particularly for the the release of Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal. The long-term goal is to have -lowlatency in the official Ubuntu repositories, while maintaining -realtime in a dedicated PPA.

Comment: thanks :D I didn't know that, sadly I don't have any of those distros..

Comment: Unfortunately, Ubuntu doesn't seem to have `linux-image-rt-*` in its repositories anymore. Do you know if there is a PPA that contains these Debian packages, or even a way to download the package off of the Debian repositories for manual installation?

Comment: @Shahbaz It looks like Ubuntu has dropped the `linux-image-rt` package in new versions due to lack of support.

Comment: @Shahbaz It's possible to manually build and install a PREEMPT_RT patched kernel. You can find information on the PREEMPT_RT wiki: https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: @VilhelmGray, I know. I have one already, and it's as best configured as I my knowledge allows. I see a jitter of ~15us (which is fine) and occasional spikes of couple-hundreds of us. I wanted to try an already configured kernel in the hopes that people more experienced than me have come up with a better configuration.

Comment: @Shahbaz I don't want to digress too far from the scope of this question, but I recommend investigating possible hardware causes for your spikes; I've encountered similar cases of latency spikes in your microsecond range which ended up being caused by service management interrupts between CPU cores -- an inherent operation behavior of the hardware which could not be adequately eliminated within software: https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Frequently_Asked_Questions#What_sort_of_real-time_performance_should_I_expect.3F

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. I don't want to digress too far from the scope of the question either. That's why I asked whether _"you know if there is a PPA that contains these Debian packages, or even a way to download the package off of the Debian repositories for manual installation"_ and didn't ask how to solve my latency issues.